# how to place the nav_header on the bottom instead of the top

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to place the nav_header (the dark grey rectangle that has brightness) on the bottom on the Nav Drawer. Can someone help me? I tried positioning it in nav_header_main.xml, but it does not reflect in activity_main.xml

[image: activity_main]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" />
<!--    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"-->
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image: app_bar_main]

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="675dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: nav_header_main]

nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/brightness_button_active"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need use `headerLayout` try this

```
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/brightness_button_active"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Comment: That's the similar way I did it in `nav_header_main.xml`,  but when I run the virtual device, it still shows up at the top :P

Comment: Yes I did! I also tried `android:foregroundGravity="bottom"` in `acitivity_main.xml`. I think `activity_main.xml` is controlling (?) that the nav_header being on top, even though in `nav_header_main.xml` the nav_header is on the bottom.

Comment: what is "defined your layout here" ? Is that the first code you suggested?

Comment: cảm ơn! I have a question, so I have an image view and text view on that nav_header, but it seem shrinked because I put a specific width, is there a way to make it look unshrinked or is depending on the image itself ?

Comment: "but it seem shrinked" could you clarify it? or show me current UI and expected your UI?